# need assistance selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i wanted add few lines in my script but iam confused what to write in it.

this is my script

```
time.sleep(1)
while True:
 X = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form/p[@class='center'][1]/img/@src")
 IF X shows
 then runpyfunctionspy
else:
 try:
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
 except:
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Restart Battle')]").click()
```

i mean if this xpath shows up then the script should run functions.py file

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form/p[@class='center'][1]/img/@src")
```

if this xpath doesnt shows up then it should continue with try

if someone can help me with this that be great!
thanks

Comment: What does it mean for `xpath` to "show"?  Define that, write the corresponding code, and you're done.

Comment: if X.is_displayed():

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not know what is XPATH,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//Mypath")
```

if you do not no how to find xpath, you can open the inspect element function in your browser. There is also an plugin called "xpath finder" By install this plugin, you can click any element that is show on the page and the plugin will automatically show the xpath.

Then , if you would like to use if

```
if element == "Text":
    print('do something here')
```